# Как получить числитель и знаменатель функции?

Tags: python, математика, numpy, sympy

Нужно построить график и исследовать функцию:

```
def f(x):
    return (x/((x-1)**2))**(1/3)

x = sp.Symbol('x')
fract = sp.fraction(f(x))

x_List = np.arange(-2, 10, 0.1)
x_List[(x_List>=1.0) & (x_List<1.1)] = np.nan

lineF = plt.plot(x_List, f(x_List), linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
```

При запуске программы график функции строится, но при попытке получить числитель и знаменатель функции я получаю такую ошибку:

```
invalid value encountered in power
  return (x/((x-1)**2))**(1/3)
```

Как я понял, вся проблема в возведении в степень 1/3 . Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В lineF Вы передаете функции f список. а в самой функции работаете со скаляром.

Comment: Проблема не в этом, в lineF для каждого элемента x_List вычисляется значение функции от этого элемента. В моем случае ошибка возникает из-за попытки возвести результат в степень 1/3

Comment: Попробуйте явно 0.333 указать... Правда мне вспоминается старый добрый способ експонента логарифма.

Comment: вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread536041.html   ответ (1/3.0) , потому что 1/3  равно нулю по правилу "целочисленное деление".

Answer (score 1):

В numpy есть функция [cbrt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cbrt.html). Так что все очень просто:

```
def f(x):
    return np.cbrt(x/((x-1)**2))
```

Comment: Спасибо). Не подскажете в чем может быть проблема, при запуске программы с уже вашим решение появляется ошибка 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cbrt'?

Comment: В приведенном коде нет никаких Mul, поэтому не подскажу. Но предположу, что в каком-то месте вы записываете в ``np`` экземпляр ``Mul``.

Comment: Я немного изменил вопрос, не посмотрите, может что-нибудь подскажете?)

Comment: Я не вижу особых изменений в сути вопроса и ответ на "как это можно исправить" уже дан.